# How do I register tastypie resources from external app?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a django based CMS system I am working on and it uses tastypie. While all resources native to the CMS are registered in a separate file imported later into urls.py some of the clients using the system require loading their own custom apps. Is there some way to register an additional resource without changing the main codebase?

Comment: What counts as the "main codebase"? Can you edit the root urls.py?

Comment: No, clients override the urls.py, which gives me the solution I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the clients in question override urls.py to include their apps. I replaced the API url pattern with a custom one and it seems to work.